# How to pass combine search argument in views_embed_view

Tags: 7, views

I create one view,that view I'm embedding in my php page using this code

views_embed_view('bank_blog_post','page','all');

In this view i added combine filter. When i search any values though this files its directly taking me into actual view url like

bank-blog-post/all?combine=IPPB+Result+2017

so how can i pass this combine filter argument also in views_embed_view function to filter my post

like mypagename/?combine=IPPB+Result+2017